# hsqldb : Database lock acquisition when connecting to a file db

Tags: java, hsqldb

I am trying to connect to a hsqldb (using version 2.2.9).

I created one using the following:

```
java -cp hsqldb-2.2.9.jar org/hsqldb/util/DatabaseManagerSwing
```

When trying to connect to the db thru my ui I'm getting the following exception:

```
Exception occured :  java.sql.SQLException: Database lock acquisition failure: lockFile: org.hsqldb.persist.LockFile@76e90d02[file =/rhel5pdi/home/mgnyp/workspace/src/Project/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/testDataBase.lck, exists=true, locked=false, valid=false, ] method: checkHeartbeat read: 2013-04-23 10:35:22 heartbeat - read: -8403 ms.
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
```

I presumed the db is locked because the DatabaseManagerSwing established a connection before my ui did, so I closed that one.
This caused the following exception:

```
 Exception occured :  java.sql.SQLException: Database lock acquisition failure: lockFile: org.hsqldb.persist.LockFile@76e90d02[file =/rhel5pdi/home/mgnyp/workspace/src/PmtMetricsUI2/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/testDataBase.lck, exists=false, locked=false, valid=false, ] method: openRAF reason: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /rhel5pdi/home/mgnyp/workspace/src/Project/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/testDataBase.lck (Permission denied)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
```

I'm using spring mvc and c3p0.
Connection details (absolute path to the db provided):

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:file:/home/mgnyp/workspace/src/Project/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/testDataBase", "SA", "");
```

I've tried this approach, unsuccessful unfortunately:
[Database lock acquisition failure and hsqldb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3968595/database-lock-acquisition-failure-and-hsqldb)

I also looked up the docs at hsql.org

Apologies if the issue is obvious, I've never used hsql before.

I would appreciate any help or hints.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to open a database that is already being used by a webapp?

Comment: Hi shyam, thank you for reply. I just discover a hanging connection to that database that I wasn't aware off, therefore the lock. It's working now, the code that was responsible for establishing connection had a design flow. It took me several hours to realized that (that's why I posted it as a question)

Comment: @mgnyp I have the same problem .Could you please explain how to fix it ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I was able to disable the lock file by including ;readonly=true as a property on the additional connection string. Otherwise I've found that the lock is always held for a file database. A sample connection string that worked for me was jdbc:hsqldb:file:my/file/location;readonly=true

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. just deleted the .lck (lock ) file and reconnected. Now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the lock with the property hsqldb.lock_file=false

example : jdbc:hsqldb:file:FILE_LOCATION;hsqldb.lock_file=false

You will find the documentation [here](https://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/dbproperties-chapt.html)