# Database lock acquisition failure with hsqldb

Tags: java, jdbc, hsqldb

I'm running this as an in-process connection, using this JDBC URL:

jdbc:hsqldb:file:C:\Program Files\360Works\SyncData2_MirrorSync\Configurations\3d0c6a29-294b-4a24-b075-70302345fdb5\mirrorsync

I am getting this error, even after completely rebooting the computer:

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.sql.SQLException: Database lock acquisition failure: lockFile: org.hsqldb.persist.LockFile@e27ecaee[file =C:\Program Files\360Works\SyncData2_MirrorSync\Configurations\3d0c6a29-294b-4a24-b075-70302345fdb5\mirrorsync.lck, exists=true, locked=false, valid=false, ] method: checkMagic magic: '0000000000000000'

How can I fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Database lock acquisition failure and hsqldb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3968595/database-lock-acquisition-failure-and-hsqldb)

Comment: Programs running without elevated privileges (e.g., not "Run as administrator") have restricted access to the %ProgramFiles% folders. Try moving the database (at least temporarily) to a location where normal users can read/write, say, "Public Documents". Or, if you only need read access to the database then try appending `;readonly=true` to the connection URL.

Comment: @Scary Wombat: I'm pretty sure this is a different type of problem than the referenced one, because I'm not attempting to connect to the HSQL database from an external process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access HSQLDB database that has lock by:

1- updating `my-db-name.properties` file and add:

```
hsqldb.lock_file=false
```

2- or removing `my-db-name.lck` file.

3- or connect to the database using pass the properties as parameters:

```
#Without Sqltool:
    java -cp [jar-path]/hsqldb-2.4.0.jar --inlineRc=url=jdbc:hsqldb:file:/[my-db-file-path]/[db-name];readonly=true;hsqldb.lock_file=false,user=sa

#With Sqltool
    java -cp [jar-path]/hsqldb-2.4.0.jar:[jar-path]/sqltool-2.4.0.jar org.hsqldb.cmdline.SqlTool --inlineRc=url=jdbc:hsqldb:file:/[my-db-file-path]/[db-name];readonly=true;hsqldb.lock_file=false,user=sa
```

Other HSQLDB database parameters can be found here, however note that only few of them can be updated after first time.
http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/dbproperties-chapt.html

Comment: Thanks, that's the best answer

Answer (score 4):

I solved the problem by manually deleting the .lck file referenced by the error message.

Answer (score 1):

Add the flowing property 
hsqldb.lock_file=false;

For example 
hsqldb.lock_file=false;hsqldb.sqllog=3;shutdown=true;syntax_ora=true

Comment: Wouldn't that make it possible for multiple processes to simultaneously write to the HSQL database files?